# Should a question be retagged to include a topic mentioned in an answer?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27773286/1426065) yesterday. It is about accessing the Yahoo Finance API, and was originally tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing), and [yahoo-finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-finance). While I was formulating an answer, someone else answered first, utilizing the [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) library. I upvoted the answer, as it was very similar to what I was thinking, but I then noticed that the answerer had edited the question to include the [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) tag, even though the OP wasn't using that library. I rolled back the edit, and left a comment that questions shouldn't be retagged to include a topic mentioned in an answer. The answerer replied and asked if I had a citation for that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging states *A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question* but doesn't specifically talk about retagging questions to include topics used in an answer.

So, is there a specific policy about this? I've searched through Meta.SE and Meta.SO, but couldn't find anything that addressed this particular issue.

Comment: That statement basically implies that tags should be based on the question and not its answers. That said, I know this was discussed on MSE somewhere...

Comment: @BoltClock right, that's how I interpreted it, but I was just wondering if that had been fleshed out anywhere.

Comment: I actually asked [almost the same question on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157688/retagging-to-include-tags-for-possible-solutions) many moons ago, and never got an answer, but got a lot of related links.

Comment: @psubsee2003 if you'd like to make an answer citing those links and summarizing their contents, I'll accept it.

Comment: related  [Should we retag questions with topics proposed in the answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59333/should-we-retag-questions-with-topics-proposed-in-the-answers)
[Retagging questions with the answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35842/retagging-questions-with-the-answer)

Comment: @MattDMo I planned on doing just that when I got enough time to pull everything together.

Answer (score 9):

I concur with your interpretation, because [a] it makes sense [b] It's clearly written in the guide: tags are meant to categorize questions.

Suppose I ask a question about an issue I'm solving in Javascript: if N users answer the question (one answer per user) suggesting many different approaches, the question tags would change from this:

```
javascript
```

to something like this:

```
javascript jquery jqueryui angularjs knockoutjs coffeescript typescript (...)
```

Might as well remove the tags altogether, they'd no longer categorize anything.